# How to add Image or logo to Email body c# windows App?

Tags: c#

I am unable to add an image to email body, windows application in c#.net.

How to add Image or logo to Email body?

Comment: What do you use to compose and send the message?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at the [ContentDisposition.Inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contentdisposition.inline.aspx) property.

So you create your attachment containing the image and then it'll have a property `ContentDisposition` that has the `Inline` property.